# How do I easily access the active value of my union?

Tags: c, struct, types, unions

How can I access the active value of my union?

For example, if I have union like this:

```
typedef union               u_signed_identifier{
 char                       i_char;
 int                        i_int;
}                           t_signed_identifier;
```

I assign the value 14 to the int variable contained in my union:

```
t_signed_identifier example;
example.i_int = 14;
```

I would like to access that value without having to call my int variable.

For example:

```
printf("my value = %d\n", example);
```

This example displays a warning when I compile with gcc.

Is there a way to access the value, without using a flag which indicates the type of the active value?

Comment: What language? C or C++?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Pick only one

Comment: Why not use a plain `unsigned int`?

Comment: I use C language

Comment: Then don't tag with C++, I removed it for you.

Comment: Short answer: no.  Accessing a member of a union that differs from the last one set gives undefined behaviour.  And there is no way to get the union to magically give back the value of the last field set.    Also, even if there was such a mechanism, printing `example` or  `example.i_int` will give undefined behaviour, since `printf()`s `%d` format specifies an `int` and your union has an `unsigned` member but no `int` member.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I reduced my union to make the question clear, but my union contains much more variable

Comment: @Peter: In C, in contrast to C++, accessing a member of a union other than the last-assigned member reinterprets the bytes of the union as the type of the accessed member (C 2011 6.5.2.3 3). It is not undefined behavior *per se*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - You missed my point.  The union does not contain an `int`, it contains an `unsigned`.  `printf()` gives undefined behaviour if an `unsigned` argument corresponds to the `%d` format.   The bitwise representations of `int` and `unsigned` differ.

Comment: @Peter You are right my example is not right, i edit.

Comment: @Peter: Your complete sentence “Accessing a member of a union that differs from the last one set gives undefined behaviour.” is false. I did not miss your point about signed versus unsigned. I merely did not comment on it, as I had no comment on it to offer. I addressed the false sentence because it was false, and it should be corrected.

Comment: This was originally tagged C++ and in C++ it would be UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Unions are unaware of the last type used. You have to either use a plain old integer or add a flag mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the C Standard suggests that unions have active members.  Instead, any action which is performed on any member of a union is simultaneously performed on all members that use the same storage.  The notion of unions having "active members" is a result of compiler writers trying to apply the "Effective Type" rules (which are so ambiguously written as to be worse than useless) to unions, despite that fact that unions and their members have declared types.

On a non-obtuse implementation for a platform which uses common floating-point types, given a union like:

```
union UF {
  uint32_t u;
  float f;
} uf;
```

the effect of writing 1.0f to `uf.f` and then reading `uf.u` would be to take the sequence of bytes associated with 1.0f [hex 00 00 00 40], IIRC and interpret that as a uint32_t, yielding 0x40000000.  Incrementing that and writing it back would cause the union to hold the byte sequence 01 00 00 40, and reading `u.f` would then yield the `float` value associated with that bit pattern, i.e. 1.00000006f.

At any point in time, both `uf.f` and `uf.u` will have values, and on a quality general-purpose implementation, the state of the universe after writing `1.00000006f` to `uf.f` would be the same as the universe after writing `0x40000001` to `uf.u`.  It's thus not possible to print out the value of the last member of the union that was written unless one has manually kept track of which member that was.

Note that there are many situations--this among them--where the Standard makes no attempt to forbid "conforming" implementations from behaving in obtuse or useless fashion.  According to the Standard, any attempt to access `uf.f` or `uf.u` would invoke UB, since such an access would use an lvalue of type `float` or `uint32_t` to access an object of type `union UF`, an obtuse implementation could process such accesses in any fashion it sees fit.

The maintainers of gcc and clang have invented a concept of "active union member" modeled after the Effective Type rules, and may not recognize attempts to read or take the address of union members other than the active one.  Reliably tracking active union members is no more practical for a compiler than tracking Effective Types, however, and their behavior in practice ends up only being conforming to the extent that the Standard imposes no requirements on code that uses *any* union members of non-character types.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can use a struct or union identifier alone to get a value. In addition, you cannot know which type that was the last one used. Because a union does *not* contain one of many types - it contains several types at once. Any attempt to use a union as a "variant" that contains several unrelated types most likely originates from bad program design  ("XY problem").

The only thing you can do is to use a pointer to the largest type contained within the union, such as

```
printf("my value = %d\n", *(int*)&example);
```

However, this has no apparent benefit over

```
printf("my value = %d\n", example.i_int);
```

(Please note that pointer tricks like these can be dangerous in some circumstances. There's the issue of "strict pointer aliasing" which doesn't apply to unions but can apply to structs.)